# MAMP PHPize Command

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I am trying to run mamp's phpize command on a source code as below:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/phpize
```

But this is giving me error as below output:

```
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:  
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
```

Do you have any idea, what is wrong here?

Comment: When you navigate to the files in the grep lines, what is there?

Comment: Actually, those files/source directories didn't installed in my 'mamp pro'. And thus, those really don't exist. I am confused how I can get those sources there, any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building/Installing XDebug on Mac OSX with MAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379903/building-installing-xdebug-on-mac-osx-with-mamp)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great guide on how to download and configure the resources that you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175197/369326